# How to deploy/host python flask rest API on local windows system?

Tags: python, flask

How to deploy/host python flask rest API on the local windows system?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World’

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: Which part of the code fails?

Comment: I need to host my python rest API on windows IIS